# Ffmpeg didn't burn srt subtitle on mkv properly

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

`ffmpeg version:git-fc6de70 (2013-07-18) with libass and fontconfig support.
command line:ffmpeg.exe -i test.mkv -vf subtitles=test.srt out.mkv
and i got this error.:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x5
76 [SAR 1:1 DAR 20:9], q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, stereo
, fltp (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvorbis)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 00000000027b9960] Neither PlayResX nor PlayResY defined. A
ssuming 384x288
```

http://tinypic.com/r/2ag52so/5

Comment: please add the complete ffmpeg output, because for now I'm not sure that someone can help you

Comment: Same as before, you updated your question without taking into account my remark, without the ffmpeg message how do you think we can figure what the mkv contains, what version you use, if it has been build with libass support....

Comment: See [Copy To the Clipboard From the Windows Command Prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/). Providing text is better than images since the text is searchable and easier to read.

Comment: @user2600010 if I understand your encoding work, I see 11 video frame encoded in your snapshot ! So what is the problem ? More details please.

Comment: @alexbuisson my subtitles getting smaller after burning and divx plus web player says we don't support that audio format but in their site i see they support aac with h264 mkv.note:pot player opens this file's audio properly.i mean it isn't broken file.

Comment: A lot of questions, but now understand your issue with subtitle and it's something known, see below for the a workaround I know it's not a perfect solution (ready for big volume) but it should work. Note that for your audio issue it's another problem !

Answer (score 7):

The message you get:

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 00000000027b9960] Neither PlayResX nor PlayResY defined. Assuming 384x288
```

means that your ssa or srt file doesn't specify the PlayResX and Y values. So the VFilter assume a display resolution of 384x288, thats why your subtitles looks so small on a 1280x576  video.

A workaround for your issue is:

1. convert SRT to SSA/ASS

   ```
   ffmpeg -i file.srt file.ass
   ```
2. edit your SSA/ASS file to set the correct value. For SSA the format is describe [here](http://matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html) and it's easy to set PlayRes X and Y.

   ```
   [Script Info]
   ; This is a Sub Station Alpha v4 script.
   ....
   ScriptType: v4.00
   Collisions: Normal
   PlayResX: 1280
   PlayResY: 576
   PlayDepth: 0
   ....
   ```
3. And finally, launch your command again using the ass file.

Answer (score 0):

Burning subntitles with FFmpeg is tricky due to canvas size with pictured-based subtitles and charset encoding with text files (srt or ssa).

I guess I managed to handle it for almost all cases in DVDx 4.1 Free Encoder version (Beta 1.0):
http://www.labdv.com/dvdx/4.1/docs/burn-subtitles-in-video.php